# Pandas - Create duplicate rows on the basis of a column value ,given a threshold for this column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas Dataframe :

```
A    B     C
20   6     7 
5    3.8   9
34   4     1
```

I want to create duplicate rows if value in A is say >10.
So the Dataframe should finally look like:

```
A    B     C
10   6     7
10   6     7
5    3.8   9
10   4     1
10   4     1
10   4     1
4    4     1
```

Is there a way in pandas to do this elegantly? Or I will have to loop over rows and do it manually..?
I have already browsed similar queries on StackOverflow, but none of them does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#get floor and modulo divisions
a = df['A'] // 10 
b = (df['A'] % 10)

#repeat once if not 0
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(b.ne(0).astype(int))]
#repplace values of A with map by index 
df2['A'] = df2.index.map(b.get)

#repeat with assign scalar 10
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(a)].assign(A=10)

#join together, sort index and create default RangeIndex
df = df1.append(df2).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A    B  C
0  10  6.0  7
1  10  6.0  7
2   5  3.8  9
3  10  4.0  1
4  10  4.0  1
5  10  4.0  1
6   4  4.0  1
```

Comment: My python hangs up on reaching the line 
**df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(b.ne(0).astype(int))]**
Any idea why ?

Comment: How working first solution? `df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(b.clip_upper(1))]` ?

Comment: @Ravikumar - OK, if use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` as first step, how it working?

Comment: what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ? Are data confidental?

Comment: Actually, I was doing a silly mistake, the values in A were of the order of 10^5, so obviously it was taking time as I didn't change the threshold value.